# Is my dog getting enough walks and eating enough food?

Tags: dogs, health

### Information about my dog

- Name - Kairo
- Breed - Korean Jindo
- Color - Brown
- Age - 2 years and 5 months old
- Gender - Male
- Weight - 15 kg

[image: He looks thin, is this normal for korean jindos?]

### Weight

He looks thin, is this normal for Korean Jindos?

### Elimination Habits

When Kairo was a puppy, he use to pee and poop in the corner of the house. But after he turned like 5 months old, I started to walk him once a day. When I started to walk him everyday, he stopped peeing or pooping in the house. But sometimes I could not walk him every single day, and when I don't walk him, he will hold up and does not pee nor poop. Once I didn't walk him for 2 to 3 days, and he still held on to it. I try to let him do it but he won't. He will just wait for me to walk him.

I got really worried about his urinary and excretory system, so after that experience, I walk him twice a day, morning and evening. Is this enough? I'm still not sure. He drinks about 3 to 3 1/2 cups of water a day. Is this routine healthy for him?

### Meals

And also, he doesn't finish his meals. I give him one cup in the morning and another cup in the evening, but he will only eat the half of it each time. So all in all he is eating just one cup in a day, which I'm really worried about. He doesn't eat the food all at once; he will eat like few bites, then after an hour, he'll take another few bites, and so on (but still eats only half of it). I'm really worried seeing him getting thinner. :( I walk him like 1 hour to 2 hours in the morning but still no changes. Is this routine okay for his health?

Answer (score 4):

> I walk him twice a day, morning and evening. Is this enough?

For most dogs, two or three walks a day is usually fine unless they have diarrhea or other health issues that require more-frequent elimination. Physically and emotionally healthy dogs will go to great lengths to avoid eliminating in whatever space they consider "home," so please don't put your dog in a situation where he's forced to go against his strong instincts to eliminate outside.

> And also, he doesn't finishes his meal.

There can be multiple reasons for this, including:

1. Lack of interest in what you're feeding. You might try different dog foods, or supplement with table scraps.
2. Self-regulation. Not all dogs will eat until they pop; many will, but some dogs eat until they're full and then stop.
3. Health issues such as gingivitis, gastric distress, or other conditions can lead to reduced appetite.

Generally, if your dog is lean but not bony, and has a reasonable level of energy, then I wouldn't treat it as an urgent matter. However, if your dog seems lethargic, is rapidly losing weight, or if you can count his ribs visually then a trip to the vet is definitely in order.

> He doesn't eat the food all at once; he will eat like few bites, then after an hour, he'll take another few bites, and so on[.]

This is not uncommon in dogs that are free-feeding, especially if they aren't food-focused or dislike the offered food. Offering a higher-quality food at scheduled times may help, but there's nothing intrinsically wrong with allowing a self-regulating dog to free-feed. Just make sure that the food isn't left out long enough to go bad.

You might also try offering something more palatable, or try foods with a different texture, like white rice mixed with cottage cheese. While it won't provide a balanced diet, is certainly contains calories and can help to put on a little weight, and will also help you determine whether your dog is simply not hungry or if you need to find a diet he likes more.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking a few questions here.

First, since your dog will not eliminate except when outside, you need to make sure he gets access to the outside regularly. It doesn't have to be a long walk each time as long as he urinates and defecates. When I take my dog outside I watch him as he pees to judge how much he's going to see if he is urinating because he has to or just to mark his turf.
I've also found it helpful to keep to a schedule; take the same route and spend the same amount of time outside each time so your dog learns to not "save" any urine (on longer walks, male dogs especially use their urine to mark their territory so they may not expel it all at the first pit stop).

As for the amount of food and water your dog is eating, I cannot say for sure but if he's not eating all the food you give him (and he's not filling up on treats or things he shouldn't be eating) then it may just be too much food for him. If he continues to lose weight, definitely take him to a vet as decreased appetite and weight loss can be symptoms of serious health problems.